# activeadmin.git (at master) is not yet checked out error when installing active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, github

[Active admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem is added to my rails project but every time i tried to install `rails g active_admin:install`, I am getting error like

> git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git (at master) is not yet
>   checked out. Run `bundle install` first.

I definitely ran bundle before running "rails g active_admin:install". After running "bundle show" i am seeing i have " * activeadmin (1.0.0.pre 3f916d6)" added to my project but keep getting this error message.My gem file below[image: Active Admin Error with bundle show]

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',

    group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2899

Comment: Sorry doesn't much info, I already tried all, explained on that thread :(

Comment: If you've updated spring recently, make sure to run `spring binstub` in your app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. It is something to do with spring as when I removed it from the gemfile and run `bundle install` again, I was able to run `rails g active_admin:install`

Comment: Dude you are genius :) , it worked, was stuck with this for last two days!

Comment: @Marcus this is perfect. I've searched everywhere for this and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: Of all solutions I've seen for this issue (different gem same issue), this is the most concise, and only one that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of removing spring you could also try this tip from [the spring github issue](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/387#issuecomment-75719710):

Try running bundle exec `spring binstub --all` - it should regenerate your `bin/spring` file